# Luigi parameter default values and mocks

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, luigi

I am trying to mock something that supplies a default value for a luigi parameter.

A dumb example showing what I'm trying to accomplish:

Task under test:

```
import luigi
from bar import Bar

bar = Bar()

class Baz(luigi.Task):

    qux = luigi.Parameter(default=bar.bar())

    def baz(self):
        return self.qux;

    def foo(self):
        return bar.bar()
```

Unit Test code:

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock, patch
from sut.baz import Baz

class TestMocking(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_baz_bar(self):
        self.assertEquals("bar", Baz().baz())

    @patch('sut.baz.bar')
    def test_patched_baz(self, mock_bar):
        mock_bar.bar = Mock(return_value="foo")
        self.assertEquals("foo", (Baz().baz()))

    @patch('sut.baz.bar')
    def test_patched_foo(self, mock_bar):
        mock_bar.bar = Mock(return_value="foo")
        self.assertEquals("foo", (Baz().foo()))
```

It appears that the luigi.Parameter logic happens earlier than the patch.

In this example, `test_patched_foo` passes and `test_patched_baz` fails.  So the patch does happen, but happens after the call from the `luigi.Parameter(default=bar.bar())` line.

Is it possible to mock and patch something called in this manner?

Comment: In the actual code, I've gotten around this by putting in a lazy-load.  Having trouble replicating the solution in my toy example, so I won't post it as a self-answer yet.  But I also don't particularly like this workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `qux = luigi.Parameter(default=bar.bar())` line into the `__init__` method for the `Baz` class. With it in outside the `__init__`, it is being set upon class definition, not instance creation, but putting it into the `__init__` will delay its creation to the point where a `Baz` instance is created. Don't forget to call the `__init__` on the `super` class:

```
class Baz(luigi.Task):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Baz, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.qux = luigi.Parameter(default=bar.bar())

    ...
```

Comment: A promising thought, but not compatible with the way luigi parameters work.  The line `qux = luigi.Parameter(default=bar.bar())` creates a field that can later be referenced as `self.qux` but it's not a `luigi.Parameter` - it's the value passed or the result of the default spec, and in this case a string.  

It might be there's a way to bypass this and use a more standard `kwargs.pop`  with a default, but I'm not sure luigi will like it.  Might try it though.